# Start EC2 for specific time XX hours and then terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminate

A customer requested an  EC2 instance for XX hours.
I created an on-demand EC2 instance and I sent the credentials to the user. He used it for a short lived calculation.
How can I terminate that EC2 instance exactly after XX hours?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to terminate an instance after a given time period is:

- Provide a **User Data script** when launching the Amazon EC2 instance
- The script should wait the given period then issue a shutdown command, such as:

```
sleep 3600; shutdown now -h
```

Also, when launching the instance, set `Shutdown Behavior = Terminate`. This means that when the instance is stopped from within the instance, it will actually be terminated.

Alternatively, you could code a **Stopinator** that would trigger at times and determine which instances to stop/terminate. For some examples see: [Simple Lambda Stopinator: Start/Stop EC2 instances on schedule or duration](https://github.com/aws-john/simple-lambda-stopinator-for-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, John(@john-rotenstein).

I tested all your suggestions.

I used the following User Data script for

**Windows instances:**

```
<script>
shutdown -s -t 3600
</script>
<persist>true</persist>
```

**Linux instances:**

```
...
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
sleep 3600
shutdown now -h
```

In addition, Stopinator Type 2 is working perfectly well for me, but only with Stop-After tag